# C++ atoi error error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I want a * each of b.
If a = 472 and b = 385, 472 * 5; 472 * 8; 472 * 3;
But Some error is occurred.
I don't know why so.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;
    int b;
    
    string c;
    
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    
    c = to_string(b);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << a * atoi(c[2-i]) << endl;
        
    }
    cout << a * b;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const Char\*' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534532/invalid-conversion-from-char-to-const-char-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

The expression `c[2-i]` returns `char`, not a `const char *`, and `atoi()` expects a `const char *` as its argument.

I think you are trying to call `atoi()` on the subset of the string starting at position `2-i`; if so, the correct syntax for that would be more like:  `atoi(c.c_str()+(2-i))`.  Note that in this expression we use the `c_str()` method of the `string` class to return a C-style `const char *` pointer, and then add `(2-i)` to the pointer to get to the `2-i`'th char after the start of the string.

Comment: Maybe he really wants the digit at that location, so instead of atoi he should subtract '0' ?  It's hard to tell because he didn't say what he was actually trying to do.

Comment: Maybe so, but an answer like `you don't really want to call atoi() anyway` wouldn't address why the error listed in this question's title occurred or what it means.  I'm assuming that the question's title represents the focus of the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to convert b to a string for other reasons. You can solve your problem like that:

```
int main(){
    int a;
    int b;
    
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    int aux = b;
    
    while(aux != 0) {
        cout << a * (aux%10) << endl;
        aux = aux / 10;
    }

    cout << a * b;
    
    return 0;
}
```